# Multi-line long equation vanishes few brackets

Tags: equations, split, eqnarray

```
\begin{eqnarray*} 
M \to {P_j}:{} & \left\{ {{{\left( {{n_1},{n_2},{{\left( {profile,{N_i},{N_i}\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} } \right){P_j},\\  & \# \left( {{N_i}\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} } \right){P_j}} \right)} \right)}_{K_P^j}}} \right)}_{K_P^j}},{{\left( {{n_0},{n_1},{{\left( {profile,{N_i},{N_i} \\ &\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} }  \right){P_j},\# \left( {{N_i}\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} } \right){P_j}} \right)} \right)}_{K_P^j}},{N_i}\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} } \right){P_j}, \\ &\# \left( {{N_i}\left( {\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{K_S^i} } \right){P_j}} \right),{N_i}\mathop  \leftrightarrow \limits^{n_S^i} M} \right)}_{K_{TS}^i = H\left( {K_p^j \oplus n_S^i} \right)}}} \right\}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

To split my long equation I used \begin{equation} \begin{split}, \begin{eqnarray*},and \begin{multline} etc. But all the time few brackets from equation just disapear as shown in figure below.

[image]

The correct equation is given below and I want to split it into 4 lines

[image]

Comment: (1) Never use `eqnarray` it is broken in many ways and only kept for backwards compatability. Use the macros from `amsmath`. (2) You cannot!!! break a `\left ... \right` construction across lines, you need to scale these manuallt. From the last image you post, you can clearly see that those fences are way too large, and the readability would benefit greatly by manual scaling. (3) Use a better construction to write above `\leftrightarrow`, for example load the `mathtools` package, it provides the missing `\xleftrightarrow{...}` that is missing from `amsmath`.

Comment: (4) Also you cannot have ``\\`` inside a `{ ... }` group, so you'll need to clean that up as well.

Answer (score 7):

Some suggestions:

- Don't overuse curly braces to group math elements. A proliferation of `{` and `}` symbols makes the code nearly unreadable -- while doing absolutely nothing for TeX's ability to actually typeset the mess.
- As @daleif has already pointed out in a comment, *do not use `eqnarray`*: It is seriously deprecated. Use `align` instead. When using `align`, use `&` only to indicate alignment points.  Don't forget to terminate lines with `\\` (double backslash).
- Don't use `\left` and `\right` for this multiline equation. It can't work. Instead, use `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg` sizing directives.
- Since there are quite a few parenthetic expressions, consider using square brackets instead of round parentheses for some of them.
- Optional: Use `\!` ("negative thinspace") directives to "snug up" subscript terms.
- Finally, again as @daleif has pointed out, load the `mathtools` package and use the `\xleftrightarrow` macro instead of `\mathop\leftrightarrow\limits`. (At any rate, `\limits` isn't needed.)

With these observations in mind, I think it's possible to display the equation across three, rather than four, rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\xleftrightarrow' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M \to {P_j}\colon 
\Biggl\{ 
&\biggl[ n_1, n_2, \Bigl( 
  \text{profile}, N_i,
  N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i})P_j,
  \# \bigl( N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i}) P_j \bigr) 
  \Bigr)_{\!K_{\!P}^j} 
  \biggr]_{K_{\!P}^j}, \\
&\biggl[ n_0, n_1, \Bigl( 
  \text{profile}, N_i,
  N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i})P_j,
  \# \bigl( N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i})P_j \bigr)
  \Bigr)_{\!K_{\!P}^j}, \\
&\quad 
  N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i})P_j,
  \# \bigl( N_i(\xleftrightarrow{K_S^i})P_j \bigr),
  N_i\xleftrightarrow{n_S^i}M 
  \biggr]_{K_{\mathit{TS}}^i = H(K_{\!P}^j \oplus n_S^i)}
\Biggr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you're right of course, I'll delete my comment